# How do I produce just the names from this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using this method :

```
Task.find(204).job.employees.map(&:name).each{|a|p a}
```

Which returns :

```
["Bob Bean", "Horatio Sans"]
```

How can I make it return *exactly* :

```
"Bob Bean, Horatio Sans"
```

Comment: Returning that *exactly* is impossible. Do you intend to have that be a string? If so it should have quotes around it.

Comment: Ah, great point. I updated it above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just want to join the array

```
Task.find(204).job.employees.map(&:name).join(", ") => "Bob Bean, Horatio Sans"
```

Comment: You're missing a space in there.